# How to get rid of unwanted photo rotation in Modern CV template?

Tags: graphics, moderncv, rotating

I'm using the popular `modern-cv` template on LaTeX (on Overleaf!) - while my photo appears correctly oriented in the Overleaf preview, it gets rotated **(unwanted!)** when I download the PDF.

Also, I'm not able to figure out ways to adjust both the height and the width of the photo - the only available options are to adjust the height and the width of the border around the photo.

```
\photo[80pt][0.4pt]{my_pic} % The first bracket is the picture height, the second is the thickness of the frame around the picture (0pt for no frame)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to TeX.SE. It's quite hard for us to understand what's happening and causing the rotation in the first place. Please post a small Minimal Working Example (MWE) so we could test it and get to the bottom of this. :)

Comment: I guess your photo has a rotation annotated in its meta information. try converting to another imge file format and hope the rotation is gone there

Comment: @olidem Thanks a lot, that did it! I converted the JPG to PNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the meta information (exif) defines the rotation and latex does not interpret it correctly. try to save the file into another format (and back if you like). If you are lucky the conversion eliminates the exif rotation.